# How can I disable the method if there is a UI on top of the object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

The code below is triggered when the player clicks on the mouse button, if there was an object under the mouse, then the object changes its material

```
private void Update()
{
       if (ClickCheck(out var hit) && hit.transform.TryGetComponent(out Script script))
       {
               script.MaterialSet(newMaterial); 
               // New material 
       } 
}

private void ClickCheck(out RaycastHit hit) 
{
      if (Input. GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
      {
             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
             
             if (Physics.Raycast(ray,  out var hit)) return true; 

             hit = new RaycastHit(); 
             return false; 
      }
}
```

How do I make it so that when clicking on the UI, the Click Check method does not work?

I tried to do a check inside ClickCheck via EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject, but for some reason the check didn't work. This example looked like this

```
private void ClickCheck(out RaycastHit hit) 
{
      bool b = EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject; 

      if (Input. GetMouseButtonDown(0) && d == false) 
      {
             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
             
             if (Physics.Raycast(ray,  out var hit)) return true; 

             hit = new RaycastHit(); 
             return false; 
      }
}
```

I have another option to make a beam that will check UI objects. But adding a Collider to each UI object is too difficult, because there are so many of them.